# Rails + Bower issue with assets path

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, asset-pipeline, bower

I have install "Tinymce" though bower into my rails app in vendor/assets/bower_components/tynymce-dist

I include js assets in application.js and it works ok

```
//= require tinymce-dist
```

then I include css files in application.css

```
@import 'tinymce-dist/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css'
```

it works, but I have an error in rails console

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css"):
```

and in chrome console

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css
```

it calls from tinymce script in that way

```
skinUrl = tinymce.baseURL + '/skins/' + skin;
```

looks like it calls absolut url.

One solucion is to use Tinymce gem, but I dont want to use this way.

How to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Bower` in your Rails app, you'll do well looking into [Rails Assets](https://rails-assets.org/):

[image]

This basically allows you to include bower-enabled assets as gems. You just have to search for the respective gem on their app, and then add the gem to your Gemfile:

[image]

RA actually have `TinyMCE-dist` already:

[image]

---

I would personally recommend using `Rails Assets` - I can delete the answer if you'd rather not. It will give you the benefits of bower and the dependability of the gem system:

```
#Gemfile
source https://rubygems.org
source https://rails-assets.org #-> add this line

gem 'rails-assets-tinymce-dist'
```

Then add the following to your JS & CSS assets:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require tinymce-dist/tinymce.js

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
@import 'tinymce-dist/skins/lightgray/skin'
```